# How can u assign IP addressing for point to multipoint switches that connect to only one router?

Tags: switch, dhcp

I was wondering if I can assign two network address in a LAN while the switches are point to multipoint which connect to only one router.
How will me DHCP going?

Router - Switch 1 - Switch 2,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if I can assign two network address in a LAN

Sure. Two different IP addresses on a single NIC require manual configuration though. IP addresses from different subnets aren't all too practical though and likely you'd want to use VLANs to separate the IP subnets on the data link layer as well.

> while the switches are point to multipoint

On the data link layer (L2), switches are always point-to-multipoint - that's their purpose. Connecting switches to each other just increases port connectivity.

> which connect to only one router.

A router isn't relevant here. Of course, if you actually segregate the IP subnets by VLANs or by dedicated switches you need a router with sufficient interfaces - VLANs can be trunked to a single physical interface though.

> How will me DHCP going?

DHCP only assigns a single IP address to each MAC address. So, unless your NIC somehow uses multiple MAC addresses, it'll only get a single IP.

Note that host configurations are off topic here and DHCP is only on topic for on-topic network devices.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I would like to ask is it a must to use VLAN for having wireless and wired connection in a LAN using point to multipoint switch. Where each switch is connect to different kind of end-devices.

Comment: @heloitsme if you want to segregate different kind of devices, yes, VLAN is the way to go.

Comment: @heloitsme There's no must - you can simply bridge wired and wireless device together, technically. However, most of the time you'd want those devices in *separate security zones* which you must segregate by VLANs or by dedicated switches. Using separate IP subnets in a shared broadcast domain isn't enough.